# Get private variable from object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the private variable `value` from this object without modifying the function `Test` itself?

```
function Module(){
    this.get = function(){
        return value;
    }
}

function Test(){
    Module.call(this);
    var value = 14;
}

Test.prototype = Object.create(Module.prototype);
Test.prototype.constructor = Test;

var T = new Test();
T.get();
```

Is it possible to extend the object/funciton `Test` in some way to get the variable `value`?

Comment: Then why should we call it _private variable_?

Comment: Create a getter or setter function for it is a possibility if you need the variable to be private.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the private variable `value` from this object without modifying the function `Test` itself?

No.

Also note that `value` doesn't even exist until `Test` is called, and a different `value` is created every time `Test` is called. In both cases, unless there's a closure within `Test` you haven't shown, the variable disappears when `Test` returns.

---

Re your updated question: Same answer. `value` exists only during the call to `Test`. It isn't saved anywhere, nor are there any closures over it, so it disappears as soon as `Test` returns.

Comment: Isn't it then possible to add a new method after the object `Test` is initiated/created?

Comment: @clarkk: No. First, let's clear something up: While `Test` is an object (because functions are objects in JavaScript), it's not the object you're thinking of. You're thinking of the object created by `new` when you do `new Test`. Again, `value` doesn't exist anymore once `Test` returns. You'd have to add a method that closed over `value`, which you can only do by modifying the `Test` function. And if you were going to modify `Test`, it would be simpler to replace the `value` *variable* with a `value` *property* (`this.value = 14;`).

Answer (score 0):

Haha, this is silly - please don't do this! But there's always a way ;D

`document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Test.toString().replace("function Test(){\n    var value = ","").replace(";\n}","");`

https://jsfiddle.net/frj3ej2p/